# How to get specific column from Parse using curl and REST API

Tags: parse-platform

I am currently using the following curl command to output the first 10 objects that are over 6 months old and save them to a text file called objects.txt.

Curl command -

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MyAppID" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: My REST API Key" \
-G \
--data-urlencode 'limit=10' \
--data-urlencode 'where={"updatedAt":{"$lt":{"__type":"Date","iso":"2014-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/MyApp > objects.txt
```

the output is an array of JSON data which has all of the columns for each object, how can i only get the ObjectID column?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: as far as I know, there is no select operation in rest api. you can use a commandline json parser such as http://stedolan.github.io/jq/ to parse the curl result

Comment: Okay, thanks ill have a look at that.

Comment: Could you give any advice or point me in the right direction of how i can use the json parser with the above curl command?

Comment: There is a quick tutorial about how to use jq with curl http://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/ you should also read its manual. I haven't used it before, but you will probably need to do something like `curl <your curl parameters...> | jq '.[] | {objectId: .objectId}' `

Comment: Ahh right Okay, i appreciate your suggestion though. Thanks!